# jQuery slideToggle confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem:
Each individual header section opens a content section. One button expands and collapses all those sections. However, the button is not functioned the way I would like it. Instead, it opens all the closed sections and if any section was left open - it closes it.

Code:

```
$(".panelStyle").hide();
$("#ExpandAndCollapseButton").click(function () {
    $(".panelStyle").slideToggle("medium");
});
$(".sectionLabels").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".panelStyle").slideToggle("medium");
});
```

Comment: Post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use slidetoggle as a "force all open" animation.  You want to use `slideDown()`

slideToggle will just toggle the current state.  slideDown will force any that aren't open to open, but leave the ones that are open alone.

Please see my change below.

```
$(".panelStyle").hide();
$("#ExpandButton").click(function () {
    $(".panelStyle").slideDown("medium");
});
$(".sectionLabels").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".panelStyle").slideToggle("medium");
});
```

I added some logic to toggle all open/close.  If none are open, then all are opened.  If one or more is already open, the all are closed.

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QwbNj/1/

Here is the code.

```
$("#clickme").click(function () {
    if($(".openme:visible").length == 0){
        $(".openme").slideDown();
    } else {
        $(".openme").slideUp();
    }

});
$(".menuwrapper").click(function () {
    $(this).find(".openme").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Sorry the button name is a bit misleading - the button actually expands and collapses all, please see the change in question

Comment: How do you decide when it should open or close all?

Comment: I added a jsfiddle to my answer that has some logic built into it to decide when to open or close all.  I think this should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the illogicality of this problem - no wonder i couldn't find a solution myself - the funny thing is I had a solution similar to yours but wasn't happy with it because i wanted the button to read the users mind LOL :)

Comment: LOL, no problem.  Good luck with your solution